# Shadowing generic method class constraint

Tags: c#, generics

Is there a way store `IReturn<T> ... where T : class, IFeatureX` in variable type `IReturn<IFeatureX>` or can you explain why this cannot be done?

---

Lets say that I have a container constructor:

```
public ContainerX(IReturn<IFeatureX> body) : this()
{
    Body = body;
}
```

I want to say that IFeatureX extends also `class`, I have tried changing the constructor to private and using:

```
public static ContainerX CreateInstance<T>(IReturn<T> instance) 
  where T : class, IFeatureX => new ContainerX { Body = instance };
```

However c# does not know that `IReturn<T> ... where T : class, IFeatureX` is `IReturn<IFeatureX>`.

It seems that I cannot cast or safe cast it.

I cannot use `object` or `dynamic` because `IFeatureX` is actually `IProtobufBody` and it is a label interface that I use to make a integration test level guarantee that all assemblies that store instances in the container have a protobuf contract defined.

Comment: `IFeatureX => new ContainerX { Body = instance };` is surely something that is evaluated **at runtime**, whereas generics are a **compile-time** feature. What exactly would you achieve by this assignment? Just ommit the `new` part. Anyway `IFeature` is a really bad name for a class. Most people would interpret the leading `I` as an indicator for an interface.

Comment: @HimBromBeere like I mentioned I replaced IProtobufBody with IFeature so that it would not sidetrack attention, the same way ContainerX is actually a RabbitMq message storing servicestack request, a "promise" to return response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, the other answers were not applicable. In this particular case the answer was to have

```
IReturn<T> ... where T : FeatureBase
```

and have instances extend FeatureBase.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to make `IReturn<T>` *covariant* by declaring it as `IReturn<out T>`. You can read more about covariance and contravariance [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/creating-variant-generic-interfaces).

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem of covariance and contravariance ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance)).

Lets say you have a class called `Dog` which inherits from `Animal`, consider the following code:

```
List<Dog> l = new List<Dog>();
List<Animal> la = l;
la.Add(new Giraffe()); // this is not allowed
```

This example shows why it is not allowed by default.

There are the keywords `in` and `out` that lets you use the contravariance and covariance like `IReturn<in T>`or `IReturn<out T>`.

When you use `in`, then you can store a `IReturn<Object>` object in a variable of type `IReturn<Class>` and define functions in `IReturn` that use `T` as input variable Type.

When you use `out`, then you can store a `IReturn<Class>` object in a variable of type `IReturn<Object>` and define functions in `IReturn` that use `T` as return Type.

If you need `T` to be an input variable type in some functions and a return type in other functions, then you can only work with the exact class.